# Question on n-manifolds

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

It seems to be more of a conceptual problem than anything, but I was wondering, if a manifold $M$ can be locally parametrized (homeomorphic) by a coordinate chart $F:(u_1,....,u_n) \rightarrow p \in M$, can the manifold have dimension greater than $n$? Also why is it that the manifold has dimension $n?$

I would appreciate some clear clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension is the dimension of the space in which the local parametrization is defined, and the dimension cannot be greater.

See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain

Comment: Yes I am aware of this theorem, however maybe I dont fully grasp the theorem or the proof, but I still dont understand why it cant have dimension greater than the dimension of the euclidean space it is defined.

Comment: The relevant statemen is in the 'Consequences' section: "...if $m\neq  n$. Indeed, no non-empty open subset of $R^n$ can be homeomorphic to any open subset of $R^m$ in this case."